# actor update in DDPG algorithm (and in general actor-critic algorithms)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

The update equations for the parameters of the actor and the critic are:
$$ \delta_t  =   r_t+\gamma Q^\omega (x_{t+1},a_{t+1})-Q^\omega(x_t,a_t)$$
$$ \omega_{t+1}  =   \omega_t+\alpha_\omega \delta_t \nabla_\omega Q^\omega(x_t,a_t) $$
$$ \theta_{t+1} = \theta_{t}+\alpha \nabla \mu_{\theta}(x_t)\nabla_a Q^\omega(x_t,a_t)|_{a_t=\mu_\theta(x_t)} $$

They can be verified [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/silver14.pdf), the DDPG paper.

I understand the 3rd equation (top to bottom), as one wants to use gradient ascent on the critic. I understand $\delta_t$ (if we assume $\gamma=1$) is the "error" made by $Q^\omega$. If $Q^\omega=Q^{\mu}$, where $Q^{\mu}$ is the true action-value function, then $d_t=0$.

However, I can't understand the second equation, in particular, I don't understand why $\nabla_\omega Q^\omega(x_t,a_t)$ is there. Is that to maximize $Q^\omega$, and hence the reward? if so, was not the actor doing that in the 3rd equation?

I'd appreciate if someone can provide some intuition and even better some technical motivation for equation 2. I have googled, but the answers I found did not really address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is minimizing the TD-error of the critic -- if $\delta_t$ is positive, then that means our estimate of the value of $x_t, a_t$ was too pessimistic, so we want to update $\omega$ in a way which pushes $Q^\omega(x_t,a_t)$ upwards (and vice-versa). The critic's job is not to maximize any reward, it's just to become a better critic.